# Getting null dns of newly created instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I am writing below code to get public dns of newly created instance however i am getting null

```
DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = amazonEC2Client.describeInstances(new DescribeInstancesRequest());
List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();

for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
    for (Instance instance1 : reservation.getInstances()) {

        dns = instance1.getPublicDnsName();
        if(!(dns.equals("")))
        {

            break;
        }


    }
}
System.out.println("value:" + dns);
```

Comment: Is the instance created in VPC without a public IP?

Comment: yes, but after the instance u=is created, a public dns has been assigned to it

Comment: Does this mean you are assigning an elastic IP to the instance after its been created?

Comment: I have created the instance using RunInstancesRequest()

Comment: Do the instances have public DNS? If the instances are created in a VPC and a public IP is not assigned on create, then the value of null is correct. Instances created in classic always get a public IP, but instances created in VPC may not.

Comment: @datasage I believe that by default, DNS hostnames are enabled only for default VPCs and VPCs that you create using the VPC wizard in the VPC console (both public and private). only if you provide your VPC and you do not support dns (enableDnsSupport and enableDnsHostnames set to false) you will not have the dns. I doubt the OP did all that in this case !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all non running instances, the dns name is null. You can check documentation for [`Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Instance.html#getPublicDnsName()) class

> This name is not available until the instance enters the `running`
>   state

**In case you run with a VPC**

When you launch an instance into a VPC, Amazon provides the instance with public and private DNS hostnames only if DNS hostnames are enabled for the VPC. By default, DNS hostnames are enabled only for default VPCs and VPCs that you create using the VPC wizard in the VPC console.

Amazon supports the following VPC attributes to control DNS support. Be sure to set both attributes to true if you want your instances to have public DNS hostnames that are accessible from the Internet.

- enableDnsHostnames
- enableDnsSupport